# Is industrial hemp allowed in Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, singapore

Especially in the form of already-woven fabric. I have a backpack that's made from industrial hemp and cotton. Is it allowed in Singapore? Is there an actual law source that could confirm this? All I can find is people who are confused about what (industrial) hemp is in the first place at TripAdvisor and other sites.

For reference, the backpack is something like this (not the exact model):

[image: National Geographic NG 5159 cotton/hemp blend camera backpack]

I mean this may seem a bit stupid but better safe than sorry I guess.

Answer (score 6):

I can't provide a legal source, but I will point out that you will be fine as [woven](https://zilingo.com/en-sg/product/details/PRO7118425435?color=white) [hemp](https://shopee.sg/Hemp-rope-woven-portable-shoulder-small-square-bag-i.40390924.1294379887) [products](https://singaporetradingpost.com/products/grey-handwoven-knotted-hemp-rug-1-6m-5-x-2-3m-7-a) are commonly available for purchase in Singapore.

There's also nothing listed beyond cannabis (Cannabinol; Cannabinol derivatives; Cannabis and cannabis resin) in the [reference document](https://sso.agc.gov.sg/SL/MDA1973-RG1?DocDate=20180430#Sc4-).

I wouldn't go out of my way to advertise the fact that it's hemp to avoid any misunderstandings though.

Comment: This sounds correct to me. However note that your second link (shopee) actually ships from outside Singapore, so that one doesn't really prove anything. The other two links seem to be shipping from Singapore though.